# the file tidy.h and buffio.h not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am developing app using **CXFeedParser**. But after doing all the integration,

**The File "MWImageParser.m" is generating error.**
`# import "tidy.h"` and `"buffio.h"` not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is very simply way i have found, no need to do any pod setup, just download the Tidy.h and Buffio.h from GIT Hub and include in Your project, and it will run smoothly..
Finally solved my own question.

Comment: ehmm, that was my original answer: `Simple solution is to include its source in your project`. Well, glad it's solved.

Comment: By the way @asgoth , Yes,you indeed helped me.. but that time i didn't get your point. After doing researching i found it.

Answer (score 2):

**buffio.h** and **tidy.h** is a part of [TidyLib](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/lxr/source/).

Simple solution is to include its source in your project (see `include` and `src` folder).

Other solution is to include a cocoapod [tidy-html5](http://cocoapods.org/?q=tidy-html5) (seems to be experimental, so be careful). There is a cocoapod for [MWFeedParser](http://cocoapods.org/?q=MWFeedParser) too.

Check the [Cocoapods](http://cocoapods.org/) website for more information (if you still need).

Basically, after installation (via `sudo gem install cocoapods`), you need to create the following `Podfile` in your project root, with the following content:

```
pod 'MWFeedParser', '~> 1.0'
pod 'tidy-html5', '~> 0.0'
```

Then run `pod install` and open the generated `xcworkspace`.

Note: only `Podfile` and `Podfile.lock` should be added to source control. The `Pods` directory can be ignored.

**Edit**: You are using `CXFeedParser`. If you look at the CXFeedParser [podspec](https://github.com/vgrichina/CXFeedParser/blob/master/CXFeedParser.podspec), you'll see it has a dependency with **CTidy**. So remove MWFeedParser from your project and have the following Podfile:

```
pod 'MWFeedParser', '~> 1.0'
pod 'CTidy', '~> 0.3'
```

Comment: Read the 'Install' & 'Get Started' section. After installation, you should create a Podfile with two 'pods', one for MWFeedParser, one for tidy-html5. After running `pod install`, it will generate a xcworkspace file (instead of xcproject) which will first build the pods and then your project.

Comment: Then it is even simpler, just use pod CXFeedParser